# Event listener/ Scanner in Gridworld

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, event-listener, gridworld

I'm trying to control `Bug`s in GridWorld.  I have tried two ways of doing this, neither of which have actually moved or turned the bug. They both compile but nothing happens.

Here is the `Bug` that will be controlled:

```
package info.gridworld.actor;

import info.gridworld.grid.*;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;

import java.awt.Color;

public class MazeBug extends Bug {

public MazeBug() {
    super(Color.blue);
}
public void forward(){

    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    if (gr == null)
        return;
    Location loc = getLocation();
    Location next = loc.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
    if (gr.isValid(next))
        moveTo(next);
    else
        removeSelfFromGrid();
}

public void turnRight(){
    setDirection(getDirection() + Location.RIGHT);
}

public void turnLeft(){
    setDirection(getDirection() + Location.LEFT);
}
}
```

Here is the first way that I tried controlling the bugs with the keys W,A, and D using Scanner (not sure if I used scanner correctly)

```
package info.gridworld.actor;

import java.util.Scanner;
import info.gridworld.grid.*;

public class KeyTests extends Actor
{
   public static ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld(new BoundedGrid<Actor>(20, 20));
   public static MazeBug currentBug;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       world.show();
       world.add(new Location(1,11),new MazeBug());
       while(true){
           Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
           String buttonpress = k.nextLine();
           if (buttonpress.equals("w"))
               currentBug.forward();
           if (buttonpress.equals("d"))
               currentBug.turnRight();
           if (buttonpress.equals("a"))
               currentBug.turnLeft();
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is the 2nd way I tried to control the bug

```
package info.gridworld.actor;

import info.gridworld.grid.*;

public class KeyTests extends Actor
{
    public static ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld(new BoundedGrid<Actor>(20, 20));
    public static MazeBug currentBug;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        world.add(new Location(1,11),new MazeBug());    

        java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new     java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher() {
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent event) {
                String key = javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(event).toString();
                if (key.equals("w"))
                   currentBug.forward();
                if (key.equals("d"))
                   currentBug.turnRight();
                if (key.equals("a"))
                   currentBug.turnLeft();
                world.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        world.show();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advanced

Comment: Try moving the controller code into the `Bugs` act method.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost positive that your problem is that you put your controlling code in the Runner instead of your Bug's act method.

When GridWorld steps all it does is call each `Actor's` `act` method, so if your `Actor` has an unpopulated method it will just call the parent, or do nothing. Your runner, since it is not an '`Actor`' has no `act` method, and after the first run is never looked at again.

Try this in your MazeBug:

```
public void act()
{
    java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new     java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher() {
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent event) {
            String key = javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(event).toString();
            if (key.equals("w"))
               forward();
            if (key.equals("d"))
               turnRight();
            if (key.equals("a"))
               turnLeft();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

**Note**: I have never used EventListeners so can't help with that code.